# Is there any (good) SQLite GUI for Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, gui, sqlite

I'm looking for a SQLite graphical administration utility for Linux but I can't seem to find any (I found an extension for Firefox I'm not a user of that browser).

Is there any that you know of?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Tried [Sqliteman](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/files/sqliteman/1.2.2/)? Look for `sqliteman` in your package manager. It is stable, so should be broadly available.

Comment: Can confirm - it's simple and effective.

Comment: On Fedora 21 I could just run: yum install sqliteman

Comment: for long text fields, it's bad. Much better alternative is sqlitebrowser (see below)

Comment: It's not actively supported anymore...

Comment: My browser reports that sqliteman website as a security risk

Answer (score 62):

I've been using [`sqlitebrowser`](https://sqlitebrowser.org), it is a really good option. Though probably not the only one!

On Ubuntu, it is available in the default package repositories.

```bsh
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

or as Snap package:

```bsh
snap install sqlitebrowser
```

Comment: Just installed. Current version is [3.12.2](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases/tag/v3.12.2) released on 2021-05-18. So I added a link and install examples for Ubuntu to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

I've used the [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) for working with sqlite3 database. It looks very well.

The project is maintained (as of 2018). For some reason it is not available in  common packages repositories.

Answer (score 10):

A friend and I made [Beekeeper Studio](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/) because we wanted a modern, easy to use SQL gui client. I'm a full time Linux desktop user, so we care about Linux.

It's 100% open source! Hope someone finds it as useful as I do. Oh, it supports sqlite, MySQL, psql, etc.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 2):

You can use for this purpose Valentina http://www.valentina-db.com/valentina-studio-overview, the program is free. It works on 3 OS: LIN, MAC, WIN. It works as with mySQL/mariaDB, so with PostgreSQL, SQLite and Valentina DB.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Just to add: free, but not open source. The pro version is $199, and adds "Report Editor, Digram Editor, SQL Diff Wizard, Query Builder". (The free version seems to have just about everything else you'd normally need, though, and working with multiple DB engines is useful.)

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this yet but looks promising especially if you're looking for a web-based interface.

[phpLiteAdmin](https://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/)